# Windows external drive names

Tags: windows, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have an external hard drive that I keep switching between multiple Windows 10 computers (say α and β), each with its own USB hub.  I see that when I plug the drive into any available slot of hub-α, it gets the same letter designation (say "G:").  Same with hub-β.  Initially I thought that perhaps the preferred drive designation is stored in some hidden file on the drive itself, but I am not able to see that.  I even did a `ls -a | grep '^\.'` from a Cygwin terminal, but to no avail.

FYI, my external drive is not partitioned.

---

Q) Where is the preferred letter designation for an external drive stored (Windows system)?

---

> Follow-up question based on @Akina's response:
>
> How are name clashes resolved once the English alphabet namespace is exhausted?

Comment: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices`

Comment: Nothing happens if you exhaust all drive letters, the last drive added won't appear. You might want to consider volume mount points: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc938934(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN